# Detect a non-ASCii string pasted into an editbox in Jquery

Tags: jquery, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

How to detect a non-ASCii string pasted into an editbox in Jquery?

The codes below work on key type only -

```
function ASCIIOnly(event) {
    var regex = /[\x00-\x7F]/;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```